# how can i convert my query in laravel 8 and 2 counts with out switch case

Tags: mysql, laravel, conditional-statements, switch-statement

```sql
SELECT districts.district_name AS District,
facilities.facility_name AS Name_Of_Health_Facility,

COUNT(beneficiaries.name) AS No_Of_Registered_Client,
COUNT(compliance_visits.facility_id) AS Compliance_visitors
FROM compliance_visits

INNER JOIN facilities  ON compliance_visits.facility_id  = facilities.facility_id 

INNER JOIN beneficiaries  ON compliance_visits.beneficiary_id  = beneficiaries.beneficiary_id
INNER JOIN `districts` ON facilities.district_id = districts.district_id
INNER JOIN talukas ON facilities.taluka_id = talukas.taluka_id

GROUP BY (facilities.facility_id)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, where we take queries as input and provide free conversion to laravel. All jokes aside, what have you tried? What are the problems you run into? You can ask for help, but you can't ask others to just do your work.